# Baffling: println prints then the line erases in Atom for arguments>1e8

Tags: julia

```
function foo(x)
    n = 0
    t = time()
    while n < x
        n += 1
    end
    sec = time() - t
    println("done in $sec seconds $(x / sec) operations/sec")
end
foo(1e7)
```

I'm on Windows using Atom latest version of everything. I run the above code and it prints fine for 1e1,..., 1e7
But for `foo(1e8)` and above, it prints the line, and then the line DISAPPEARS. I'm completely baffled by that.

It only happens in Atom (VS Code works fine). I use control-enter on the `foo(1e8)` line to evaluate it and I can see it printing the line and then the line erases by itself. For `foo(1e7)` and below, it prints fine.

Here's [the video of this with 1e8 then 1e7](https://www.screencast.com/t/vGExVSN3) and it happens on Linux too. As you can see from one of the attempts the video was able to capture the printing and erasing (see at 5 second mark in the video). When I changed to 1e7, it prints fine every single time.

everything is up-to-date: Julia 1.4.1, Atom 1.46, Juno 0.8.1 and I did a complete Julia package update as well.

Comment: Very odd, I can reproduce this on Linux as well. Also if you add `@show` before the print statement, it doesn't disappear...

Comment: ...but everything works on my system (Linux as well, maybe not entirely up-to-date). I use Julia 1.4.1, Atom 1.46.0 and I just upgraded all Juno-related extensions.

Comment: @FrançoisFévotte I recently installed (within week) same versions of Julia and Atom and updated Juno to 0.8.1. so I'm baffled. And I posted a video in the original posting

Comment: Ah, I thought my Atom version might have been outdated, and this could have given a hint about the origin of errors. But if we also have the same Atom version, I wouldn't know where to begin looking...

Comment: Given that everything seems to work well in other contexts (standard terminal, VS Code...), maybe you should file an issue with Juno?

Comment: @NilsGudat The `@show` has nothing to do with it. If you add ANY print statement above it, it basically will print that line and erase it. The odd thing is 1e7 and below, it doesn't erase the line. But for 1e8 and above, the first line you try to print gets printed and erased. So just add a println above mine and you'll see. How odd is that?

Comment: What I was saying is that for me adding `@show` means the line **doesn't** get erased anymore. I see the same behaviour for 1e8 without @show, but once it's added I can successfully print 1e8 as well.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/JunoLab/Juno.jl/issues/560. Will try to fix this next week.

Answer (score 0):

github.com/JunoLab/Juno.jl/issues/560.

(credit to  pfitzseb )